# How to print out from a nested Array List

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

This is my code so far :

```
ArrayList<String[]> data = timeTable.getTimeTableData();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){

        for (int j = 0; j < data.get(i).length; j++){
            printWriter.print("Value " + data + "\n");

        }
        //printWriter.print("Length " + data.get(j). + "\n");
    }
```

I am having an issue to print out the values, I been looking at ways to do it and that's why I am posting here. What I hold in the ArrayList values coming from the database. I am expecting 14 values altogether. I am seeing 14 values in the current out put I get however as you can see its some weird characters.

This is the output I currently get :

```
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
Value [[Ljava.lang.String;@15ad30e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2403d547]
```

Please, can someone guide or help he get the output correct?
Thank You :)

Comment: Presumably Arrays.toString(data) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just need to change

> printWriter.print("Value " + data + "\n");

for

> printWriter.print("Value " + data.get(i)[j] + "\n");

Thats because your dat.get(i) is an array of Strings. And you want to access to the j element of that array.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to pass the value back from my servelet to javascript. I know I have not mentioned it within my question. This is a snapshot of how my function looks like https://gyazo.com/034eaf2c5043c019454ec2138863d714

Comment: Would you by any chance know how to pass as a json this value back to javascript

Comment: you can create your own array or object and then for example use JSON.stringify(your_arr);

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you meant ?

Comment: I am already getting it as an array so how would I be able to sent that back to the javascript as a JSON format so I can do other things to it